# Split areas on a subdivded icosphere

Tags: mesh, faces, subdivision-surface

I created an icosphere with a subdivision level of 1. Then I added an EdgeSplit, a Solidify and a Bevel Modifier to the object. In the end I subdivided the whole icosphere. I am doing it this way because I want 20 areas which are then divided into smaller pieces and not 80 small pieces like it would happen when I would choose a subdivision level of 2.
Now it looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to split every of the 20 faces into 4 pieces. I am doing this by selecting the three middle vertexes and then use split.
Now it looks like this:
[image]

When I now try to do the same thing for the adjusting areas it does not work anymore. Maybe one vertex is already in use from the other area and therefore I can not use it anymore.
Is there any way to get the same result for every area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In *Edit Mode* subdivide your Icosphere one time
2. Select all, and [*Split*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/split.html?#faces-by-edges), Faces by Edges with <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
3. Change pivot point to *individual origins* and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale a bit smaller.
4. Add Solidify and Bevel modifiers in object mode.

Result:

[image]